# Maximum possible security with a fixed link

Tags: php, security

First of all; I'm aware that this question is strange and I will probably get a lot of downvotes for it, but I still need some more information...

Here's the problem; The company I work for maintains a webshop (PHP, MySQL, IIS). The webshop is going to give a discount to people how came from some other, third party website. After logging in to the third party website, the users are presented with a static link to the webshop (the link can contain some sort of code) [**UPDATE** we can provide the link, that's all we can do, we have no privileges whatsoever on the third party server]. If they use that link to go to the webshop they have to get the discount. If a user uses another link, or goes to the webshop directly the shouldn't get the discount.

I was thinking of using PHPs HTTP_REFERER to check if the users comes from the third party website, but that is not reliable. Is there another way to make this a bit more secure? I'm aware that we won't be able to create something that makes it completely safe, but we should at least do something that keeps the user from posting the link to a forum or sharing it by e-mail.

I hope you can help me, please don't burn me down for having to implement the request of a customer. I know this is stupid, I just need to do it and I want to do it in the best way possible.

Comment: I updated my question with some more info, basically, we have no options.

Comment: So basically, the third party site can only provide a link to your website without any additions to the querystring itself or are they able to add the querystring to the URL they're providing?

Comment: As far as I know, we give them an URL to which they link, that's it. It's all very limited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...we should at least do something that keeps the user from posting
>   the link to a forum or sharing it by e-mail.

Not really. The best you can do is use a combination of HTTP_REFERER and a secret code embedded in the link, but the former is simple to fake and the latter is simple to copy. You're essentially asking to publish a phone number without letting anybody know what the phone number is.

Edit: If you've got some influence over the remote 3rd party site, you could make a joint agreement to change the secret code on a regular (daily?) basis. Or better, if you can both do this programatically, then you can set the code expiry to a very short time (e.g. one minute) -- this would make forum postings useless.

Comment: Yeah, the idea of a changing link was my first suggestion, but unfortunately the third party will probably not be able to do that...

Comment: Can you programatically push them a new link? I.e., write a script that causes their link to update, without any human intervention on their end? Then you can generate a new link every day on your side and batch push it to them.

Comment: A good idea as any, but still, I don't think that will be an option... :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think it's a stupid question at all :)

The HTTP_REFERER approach doesn't sound too bad.. You're right it's not completely waterproof, but you have to rely the user's browser to tell you where he's coming from anyway - there's no other way. I'd say a combination of a special link and checking the HTTP_REFERER on your end should do pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Have the link call a javascript function that forms a url to your PHP script that passes the window location href as a parameter.  Then in the php script, test that the href matches the expected origination point.

Comment: This would be okay, one would still be able to fake it, but it would make it more difficult. Too bad we can only supply a static link, so I don't think we would be able the add the javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

Your affiliate-site generates a unique-string which is embeded in the link to your site.

```
$link=md5($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."Very secret string");
echo '<a href="http://yoursite.com/ref='.$link.'">Claim your rebate now!</a>';
```

On the receiver side:

```
if($_GET["ref"]==md5($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."Very secret string")){
    applyRebate();
}
```

Comment: You can't use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in the hash, but the idea is okay. But again, we have to supply a static link.... 'scuse me, you already updated it, using HTTP_USER_AGENT would be okay